# Linked List - Inserting to front of the list

Tags: c++, linked-list

How would you insert a piece of data (a string) to the front of a linked list? Without getting rid of or overwriting any current data.

the class I'm working on:

```
public:
        typedef size_t size_type;
        typedef node::value_type value_type;
        SuperList();
        bool isEmpty() const;
        bool isFull() const;
        void insertFront(string newItem); // will insert newItem to front

private:
        node* headptr;
        size_type howmany;
```

Also this node class is included so I may use any functions from it. All the functions do as they are named (ie. addToEnd() adds a node to the end)

```
class node{
    public:
        // TYPEDEF
        typedef string value_type;

        // CONSTRUCTOR
        node(
            const value_type& init_data = value_type( ),
            node* init_link = NULL
        )
        { data_field = init_data; link_field = init_link; }

        // Member functions to set the data and link fields:
        void set_data(const value_type& new_data) { data_field = new_data; }
        void set_link(node* new_link)             { link_field = new_link; }

        // Constant member function to retrieve the current data:
        value_type data() const { return data_field; }

        // Two slightly different member functions to retreive
        // the current link:
        const node* link() const { return link_field; }
        node* link()             { return link_field; }

    private:
        value_type data_field;
        node* link_field;
};

// FUNCTIONS for the linked list toolkit
std::size_t list_length(const node* head_ptr);
void list_head_insert(node*& head_ptr, const node::value_type& entry);
void list_insert(node* previous_ptr, const node::value_type& entry);
node* list_search(node* head_ptr, const node::value_type& target);
const node* list_search(const node* head_ptr, const node::value_type& target);
node* list_locate(node* head_ptr, std::size_t position);
const node* list_locate(const node* head_ptr, std::size_t position);
void list_head_remove(node*& head_ptr);
void list_remove(node* previous_ptr);
void list_clear(node*& head_ptr);
void list_copy(const node* source_ptr, node*& head_ptr, node*& tail_ptr);
void addToEnd(node*& head, string newVal);
int position(node* head, string newVal);
```

Comment: your question is not well defined.  which end do you consider the front? and which end is the back?  based on your function declarations, it looks like there's the head and the end (or tail).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will return a new linked list with s as first element and some_list as the rest:

```
node *add_to_head(node *some_list, const string &s) {
   return new node(s,some_list);
}
```

**added**. Now I see that you are given a function to insert an element in the head. So you should simply use it:

```
list_insert(head_ptr, some_string);
```

the list_insert function could be implemented like this:

```
void list_insert(node *&head_ptr, const string &s) {
    head_ptr = new node(s, head_ptr);
}
```

Comment: the function prototype is void so am not allowed to return anything

Comment: Yea I figured it out before you updated it but yes this works :P

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider making the linked list class a friend class of the node class so it can access the node members, or just make the node class members public, since these are pretty generic members. Also most of the functions you show are really meant for the list class.

As for inserting at the front of the list, you set the new nodes next pointer (what you call link field) to the current front of the list, then the front of the list to the new node.